# Linux is there a way to list a specified number of lines in a repository and sub repositories

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, repository

I want to write a shell script which takes as input a valid path, and the script lists the first n (also a parameter) lines of all the files from the repository and sub repositories where the user who launched the script has read and write privileges.

Is there a command that would allow me to do this? I believe that n would be written like $1 to indicate that it is a parameter, but I am not sure what command to go with to list the lines of all the files from the repository.

I apologize if this is a simple solution, I am just currently baffled.

Comment: Use the `find` command to recurse into the directory, and execute `head -n $lines` on each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f -readable -writable -exec head -$1 {} +
```

Pass the number of lines to print as a parameter and then find all files in the current directory structure that are both readable and writable. Execute head with the passed parameter on as many files as possible with each exec (using +)